# Is there any way to plot function from other function?

Tags: plotting, functions

For example, I have a function

`W[L_, m_] := 1 + 3 L + 2 L^2 - 6 m - 6 Lm + 6 m^2`

I also have

```
r = m/L
```

What is the easiest way to plot `W`-function from `r`?

Now I just manually plug in expression for `r` in `W` and obtain

```
W[L_, r_] := 1 + 3 L + 2 L^2 - 6 r*L - 6 L (r*L) + 6 (r*L)^2
```

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you should not use upper-case letters for variables or names beginning with upper-case letters as they might conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

```
w[l_, m_] := 1 + 3 l + 2 l^2 - 6 m - 6  l m + 6 m^2

z[l_, r_] := w[l, m] /. m -> r l

w[l, m]
```

(* 1 + 3 l + 2 l^2 - 6 m - 6 l m + 6 m^2 *)

```
z[l, r]
```

(* 1 + 3 l + 2 l^2 - 6 m - 6 l m + 6 m^2 *)

Comment: Or just `w[l, r*l]`.

Comment: @march  I interpretted Maria's question to require a *function* (with slots) with the substitution.  But yes... if you need merely compute `w` with the substitution, your answer is fine.

Comment: True. But it's always worth letting the new users see multiple ways of doing things of course. But I think you accidentally removed the edit I made: `r -> r l` should be `m -> r l`, as illustrated by the output of `z[l, r]` that you copy-and-pasted.

Comment: Should it be ` r -> m/l` ? Is there any difference if I write `z[l_, r_] := w[l, m] /. m -> r l` or `z[l_, r_] := w[l, m] /. r -> m/ l` ?

Comment: @Maria. You should experiment with the different expression that you've written down and see which one works! It's the best way to learn *Mathematica*.

Comment: just didn't understand the output of `z[l,r]` in answer, but now I see that the function should appear with new variable as `l (l (6 (r-1) r+2)-6 r+3)+1`.